# Criteria to get last not null record present

Tags: database, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api

I have a daily record table where records are stored date wise. I am using hibernate criteria to access data. How do i get the last date till which records are present continuously (date wise continuity) by providing a date range. For example, say records are there from 21-09-2012 to 25-09-2012 , again from 27-09-2012 to 31-09-2012. I want to form a query using criteria to get record of date 25-09-2012 because for 26-09-2012 there are no records (by passing date ge  21-09-2012 and date le 31-09-2012) . I want to know the last date till which records are present continuously. Say the table has three fields - 1.recordId (AI) 2.date 3.Integer record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a proper solution to your question. But it may be scenario specific.
How about getting the data for a date range and show then on a calender. Change the color of date if the corresponding value is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think HQL will be better way to this in Hibernate:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html